Yaml manual approval step in jobs.template
I have a similar yaml with multiple jobs.template definitions and i would like to add a manual approval step in between the - template steps. Is there an easy way to do it or do i need to redo the entire yaml?
# File: jobs/build.yml

parameters:
  name: ''
  pool: ''
  sign: false

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}
  steps:
  - script: npm install
  - script: npm test
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.sign, 'true') }}:
    - script: sign
YAML

Copy
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- template: jobs/build.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: macOS
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-latest

- template: jobs/build.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: Linux
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

- template: jobs/build.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: Windows
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    sign: true  # Extra step on Windows only

I have already tried to add - task: ManualValidation@8 but it does not work as I get an error saying Unexpected value 'task'

ManualValidation@8 does not exist - are you confusing with ManualIntervention@8?

You cannot add a task directly between jobs - use a job or job template instead.
Example:
jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    pool: server
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'

  - job: doSomething
    dependsOn: waitForValidation
    displayName: Do something
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: |
          echo "Do something"
        displayName: Echo message

Note:

ManualValidation@0 is only supported in YAML pipelines and can only be used in an agentless job of a YAML pipeline
Remember to set the dependsOn on the job(s) that are depending on the manual validation job
In pool: server, the value server is a reserved keyword which indicates this is an agentless job

Running the pipeline:

Approve/reject dialog:

Rejecting:


thank you very much for this great response. I added a new template that has inside a job with a ManualValidation task and is exactly what i need
